# CSS or script on top of page content in one location, want text under it but the script to be on top of it

Tags: css

What I am trying to do is make a script for a little chat window be in one position with the content under it (content being the page/whole site). I want the script item to be visible on the whole site in the bottom right corner of the screen. I do apologize that this question is not very concise and to the point, as I am unsure how to ask the question that I want answered. Here is an example of what I want:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmg9j.png)

The site I am trying to do this on is [Troop-59.com](https://troop-59.com)

and here is my script :

```
    <script>
  (function(w,d,u){
                var s=d.createElement('script');s.async=true;s.src=u+'?'+(Date.now()/60000|0);
                var h=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];h.parentNode.insertBefore(s,h);
        })(window,document,'https://cdn.bitrix24.com/b9371139/crm/site_button/loader_2_p9tu23.js');
  </script>
```